# Can a mucocele on the lip pop up and become a canker sore?

Tags: oral-health, herpes, canker-sores

Is this a normal feature? Or, if this happens, it has to be an herpes sore? Are there mucoceles (because of a bite, for example) that lay a sore? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Mucoceles can rupture.  Usually that will resolve them though.  If it persists, it needs a doctor most likely.  You can find more details on that here and explanation of what a doctor would do for one that isn't resolving after rupture. http://www.steadyhealth.com/medical-answers/oral-lesions-oral-mucocele-and-canker-sores